# Smartface 4.5 Can't connect to iOS device

Tags: smartface.io

I recently purchased an Individual licence for Smartface 4.5 on my PC, and have been having 0 luck in getting the device emulator to work for either of my two iOS devices. The error is always the same: "Keep calm ;) 
You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again." 
On both devices I have the latest iOS version, the latest smartface-in-action version, and have the latest version of iTunes installed on my PC. I'm using a genuine usb cable, and have turned off anti-virus and firewall. The two devices are an iPhone 6 plus and an iPad mini, no matter what I do I cannot get Smartface to detect the app. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Same here.. Can't use Smartface with the iOS emulator. I have an iPhone 6S.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually read my confirmation e-mails... They provide a link to download the most up-to-date version and it works! Just look through your e-mails if you were in my boat and be sure to download it directly on your iOS device.